# How to count how many times a variable was used | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, repeat

The program will ask for the world size and then randomly generate a grid (the first block) based on the world size. For the first election block, I would like it to be random, but as the code generates more blocks, they aren't so random. What I mean by this is that after the first block, the program will look at the first block and determine who may change "teams." Then, after the second block, the next block will take a look at the second and, once again, determine who may change "teams." And so on.

The program will look at each line of a single block individually and determine how many Gs, Rs, and Bs are from the line. It will randomly pick a couple of letters to change in that line.
Gs can change to any team (stay the same, change to B, or change to R), while Rs and Bs can only change to B or R. So, in the first line, G will randomly be assigned a team, but the R, although it could stay the same or change to B, it could only change if it isn't the majority of the whole block. Bs and Rs can only change teams if the entire block doesn't have the majority of that team. It switches to the team that is the majority in the whole block, but the letter will randomly pick a team if Bs and Rs tie in the block. Now, if there is a majority of Gs in the whole block, then Bs and Rs can only change once Gs are not the majority.

When the program has gone through each line in the one block, it will create a new block with the changes and repeat the same process. The plan is to have the program stop when the whole block is filled with ONE team (either R or B). The program will print something that says "team name" has won.

This is my currnt code:

```
import random

# varibles
red = 'R'
blue = 'B'
undecided = 'G'
teams= [red,blue,undecided]
world = []

# Determines how big the grid will be
WORLDSIZE = int(input('What is the world size (y x y)?'))


def createWorld():
    for i in range(WORLDSIZE):
        world.append([])
        for j in range(WORLDSIZE):
            voter = random.choice(teams)
            world[i].append(voter)
            

def printWorld():
    print (' ')
    print("Current Election Poll is:")
    for i in range(WORLDSIZE):
        print( world[i] )
    count = red.count(red)
    print ('Current Results')
    print ('Red Voter:' , count)
    print ('Blue Voter:')
    print ('Undecided:')
    print (' ')
```

[Pic of Code with what it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlhon.png)

The problem I am having is that the code will not read how many times red, blue, or undecided was used in that one block. I only want it to read it for the one segment, as when I code the other parts (to make more blocks) I want it to not count the previous amount.

Comment: You are adding the votes to `world` but then you are checking the count in `red`, not `world`. You should be doing something like `red_count = sum(row.count(red) for row in world)`.

Answer (score 1):

what about make team as a dict to store both team and counter?

```py
teams = {
 'R':0,
 'B':0,
 'G':0
}
#use random
voter = random.choice(list(teams.keys()))
world[i].append(voter)
teams[voter]+=1 #counter add one
```